# Connecting a 5 V signal to a 3 V tolerant pin of a PIC

Tags: microcontroller, pic, datasheet

I have a situation that happened in my case, where i'm putting an AC signal that goes from 0 to about 4,5 V in a 3 V tolerant pin of a PIC.

The pin in question is `RE6` of a `PIC32MX470F512L`.

From the datasheet we see that this pin has a white color while the 5V pin tolerant have a gray color:

[image]

[image]

The signal is a square wave that goes from 0 to about 4.2V.

My question is, what happens to that input pin of the pic? Does it get damaged?

Comment: You've loaded image 2 twice and image 3 is missing.

Comment: @Transistor fixed, thanks.

Comment: This isn't 5 V as the PIC expects, referenced to it's ground. This signal goes between -3 V and +1.2 V

Comment: Hello @DDuck i'm measuring only the AC there, and the signal is inverted, it starts from 0 and goes to near the 4.2V.

Comment: I would have take photo of the trace when the probe is on the pin of the device, dc coupled and the ground of the scope connected to the ground of the PIC to show really what the PIC sees. Unless, of course, your question really is how do I couple this signal into the pic to 1) measure it's frequency (or duty cycle) - digital in; or 2) measure a voltage as an analog in

Comment: @DDuck i removed the image because it was causing confusion, what i really want to know is if it can somehow damage the pic, or the pin of the pic.

Comment: As well as damage you should consider how the injected current may affect operation of the MCU. I know of one commercial product that used a PIC running at 3.3V with I2C pullup resistors going to 5V that misoperated due to injected current - even though the current was less than 1mA. Sloppy engineering resulted in a lot of unhappy customers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'non-5V tolerant pins' have an internal high side diode to VDD. If the signal can supply more than 5mA (see the datasheet) the diode will be destroyed, followed by the input circuit to the PIC. So to answer your question, not only will this this input pin get damaged, but possibly other parts of the PIC too.

One solution, as Dirk Bruere mentioned, is to place a resistor in series with the input. Any value between 200 Ohms (5mA) and 1 MOhm (~1uA) should work, 10 kOhms being a sensible value (0.1mA).

Answer (score 3):

if you out 4.2V on it a pic pin that only want 3.3V something will break.

Perhaps use a resistive divider.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRXbLM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, and something I have used on other devices, is just to feed the signal via a suitable resistor. The chip inputs are normally diode clamped with a specified maximum current. As long as you don't exceed that current it should be OK

Comment: What do you mean by something will break? The pin of the Pic will get damaged? Because I already did that.

Comment: @Nmaster88 I mean the diode will burn out and other parts of the chip will be damaged if the input current is exceeded. So make sure the resistor in series with the pin allows no more than that current to flow